# why state updated in redux dev tools but it's not update in real state redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, action, reducers

I create modal for login when user submit the button , dispatch auth for send email and pass and history and after the response was okay it should dispatch idToken and isAuthenticated and in reducer should update isAuthenticated to true and store idToken but when i use it in my component i see just default state but in redxu devtools i see the state updated

action.js

```
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status == 200) {
          history.push("/dashboard");
          return dispatch({
            type: AUTH_SUCCESS,
            payload: {
              idToken: response.data.idToken,
              isAuthenticated: true
            }
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response.data.error.message);
        // dispatch(authFail(error.response.data.error));
      });
```

reducer.js

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AUTH_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        idToken: action.payload.idToken,
        isAuthenticated: traction.payload.isAuthenticated
      };
    }

    case AUTH_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        errorCode: action.code,
        errorMessage: action.message
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

privateRoute.js

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

  const authenticated = useSelector((state) =>console.log('state',state.auth));

///state not updated ????

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        authenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
      }
    />
  );
};
export default PrivateRoute;
```

store.js

```
import { compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import rootReducer from "../services/reducer";

export default (initialState) => {
  // initialState = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('state')) || initialState;

  const middleware = [thunk];
  let enhancer;

  enhancer = compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  );

  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, enhancer);
  // store.subscribe(() => {
  //   const state = store.getState();
  //   const token = {
  //     token: state.auth
  //   };
  //   window.localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(token));
  // });
  return store;
};
```

combinereducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import authReducer from './auth/reducer';

export default combineReducers({
    auth:authReducer
})
```

app

```
const Root = ({ children, initialState = {} }) => (
  <Provider store={store(initialState)}>{children}</Provider>
);
```

state in app doesn't update but in redux devtools show that my state is updated

Comment: I wonder how it's even showing in the redux devtools, when you are using `traction` instead of `action`

Comment: You have some inconsistencies in variable names as @PraneethParuchuri said. And Redux DevTools is showing the real state, it is not a different state. I believe you have some synchronous timing issues. I would not expect to see the `history.push()` function before the line that updates the state inside your action.js code.